# export datagridview to Excel Error in script

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

I have a new problem, I want to export a datagridview to excel and have a script searched for it. The script that I found gives me an error in this line.

"ExcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvTabelle.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();"

The whole script looks like this!

```
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        sfd.Filter = "Excel File|* .xlsx";
        sfd.FileName = "Flugxyz";
        sfd.Title = "Speichern von Flugdatei";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            //Storing header part in Excel
            for (int i = 1; i < dgvTabelle.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dgvTabelle.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            //Storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvTabelle.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j< dgvTabelle.Columns.Count; j ++)
                {
                    ExcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvTabelle.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(sfd.FileName.ToString());
            ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
            ExcelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.NullReferenceException" ist in FurriSoft.exe aufgetreten.

Zusätzliche Informationen: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.

Picture:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqH-JF9ioa2lhWUIgRrB1WN3X4Ir

Comment: You should check and make sure the cells `Value` is not null before you attempt to call ToString. This exception will be thrown if `Value` is null. An extra if statement like: `if (dgvTabelle.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)`... should fix this.

Comment: @Nero8Eye - english sir.

Comment: thanks for the help.